# How would one use USB On The Go to mount a USB drive without rooting?

Tags: android

There is already a Nexus Media Importer application, but I want to determine how to do that for myself as a way to learn about the protocol. How would I start? What would I need to do?

I went through the USB Host portion of the AndroidDevelopers guide, but I was unable to determine how to browse for folders or files on the USB device itself.

My target device is the Nexus 7 on Android 4.2, if that helps any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done host-mode on my Nexus 7, but on my Asus the usb drives would just get mounted in `/mnt/usbdisk_1` or similar. Just look in `/mnt` and see what you find.

Comment: ES File Manager shows nothing whenever USB is plugged in, at the moment at least. It might be a device-to-device thing.

Comment: Try it from code. `File mnt = new File( "/mnt" ); mnt.listFiles();` and don't forget `File.listRoots();`

Comment: When I display the results of mnt.listFiles() and mnt.listRoots(), I get five results: sdcard (nothing there, normal stuff), obb (nothing there at all), asec (application installs for Max Payne and GTA Vice City), secure (setting mnt to this folder causes the application to crash by nullpointer exception to mnt.length), and shell(same as secure).


I can't find anything obvious if that's the case.

Comment: Gotcha, it must work differently than it did on the ASUS then. Can't locate my OTG adapter, probably left it at a client's. I'll check next week.